# Tmux doesn't read tmux.conf on startup if its in ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf but works if I put it in ~/.tmux.conf

Tags: tmux

When placed in `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`, Tmux does not read the configuration file on startup. It works if I source it afterwards. However if I kill the tmux server and start it again it reverts to default configuration until I source the file again.

If I place the config in `~/.tmux.conf` it does read it at startup. But I would like to place it in `~/.config/tmux` like my other configs.

Comment: What is the output of `tmux -V`?